# topography mesh from 2d lines

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've got contour lines (from AutoCad) that represent a topography. The lines are already in the correct z (height) position. 
[image]

What's the best way to create a mesh out of this in Blender?
What I'd like to end up with is something like this:
[image]

Thanks for your input which is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are contour lines like a bump map? In that case maybe try a Displace modifier? Maybe share your file so that we can try: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/